# package acronym index of abbreviations

Tags: xetex, acronyms

I like to use the acronym-package to build a index of abbreviations. But I need a way to customize the index of abbreviations visually. Unfortunatly I couln't find anything related to this topic. Please advice and many thanks.

current look (acronym):

[image: current look (acronym)]

how it should look like (nomencl):

[image: how it should look like (nomencl)]